# Send a message in WhatsApp group using Graph API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I have created a WhatsApp business App on
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

I am able to send messages using the API & Access Token

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages' \
  -H "Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  -d '{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "1650XXXXXXX",
    "text": {"body" : "hi"}
   }'
```

**I want to send the message in a WhatsApp group, any ways to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API to send messages in WhatsApp Groups.

Comment: I'm trying to look for updated documentation to send to Community Group, but seems it's still not possible. That's Why WhatsApp will probably loose against Discord